# Getting SubString from String in Java(Android)

Tags: java, android, string, android-studio

I have a String name `packageName="https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MoversGames.DinosaurWorldGame";` 
How i can get `subString` from this string. I want to take `"id=com.MoversGames.DinosaurWorldGame"` this from String `packgeName`. The length of this String may change. It is not constant its variable .

Comment: you can do it using regex

Comment: @NawnitSen Regex? You could also do it with a 3rd party webserver, but why would you need so powerful for something so simple.

Comment: Just split the String with the delimiter `?` and you will get your result.

Comment: @NickCardoso that is the first thing that came to my mind.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `String.substring()`

Try to substring your string from the index of `id` to `length` of your `string`

In this below example i have started substring from index of **`?`** +1 so it will start `substring` your string from `id`  to length of your string

**SAMPLE CODE**

```
    String packageName = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.MoversGames.DinosaurWorldGame";

    String answer = packageName.substring(packageName.indexOf("?")+1, packageName.length() );
    Log.e("ANSWER", answer);
```

**OUTPUT**

```
2018-10-11neel.com.myapplication E/ANSWER: id=com.MoversGames.DinosaurWorldGame
```

Comment: Thank you bro..you saved my time which was too critical!

Answer (score 0):

There might be also some more query parameters in your String , so you can also try it like this :

```
String packageName = "https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?i 
id=com.MoversGames.DinosaurWorldGame&x=y&z=a";

String answer = packageName.substring(packageName.indexOf("id"));
System.out.print("ANSWER", answer);
```